# Missing font using html2canvas and recharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html2canvas, recharts

I'm trying to fix a bug that's driving me crazy... I have a chart from `recharts` in my React app, and export in to PNG file with `html2canvas` library. The issue is, it changes the font in chart for some reason... Anyone had issues with that?

I have a hook that returns `exportAsImage` function.
Exported image should have Proxima Nova font (it works in DOM), or at least `sans-serif` font, instead it has `serif`
Other exported elements have correct font, so it got me thinking it could be something with either `html2canvas` having issues with rendering SVGs, or `recharts` doing something weird

```
export const useExportAsImage = ({ fileName, backgroundColor, type = 'image/png' }) => {
  const refForExport = useRef();

  const saveAs = useCallback((uri, filename) => {
    const link = document.createElement('a');

    if (typeof link.download === 'string') {
      link.href = uri;
      link.download = filename;
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    } else {
      window.open(uri);
    }
  }, []);

  const exportAsImage = useCallback(() => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
      return null;
    }

    const element = refForExport?.current;

    if (!element) {
      return null;
    }

    return html2canvas(element, {
      backgroundColor,
      scrollY: -window.scrollY,
      useCORS: true,
      onclone: (doc) => {
        // toggle HTML elements
        doc.querySelectorAll('.watermark, .png-hidden').forEach((element) => {
          element.toggleAttribute('hidden');
        });
        // svg sizing fix
        doc.querySelectorAll('svg').forEach((svg) => {
          svg.setAttribute('width', svg.getBoundingClientRect().width);
          svg.setAttribute('height', svg.getBoundingClientRect().height);
          svg.style.width = null;
          svg.style.height = null;
        });
      },
    }).then((canvas) => {
      saveAs(canvas.toDataURL(type, 1.0), fileName);
    });
  }, [fileName, backgroundColor, type, refForExport, saveAs]);

  return {
    exportAsImage,
    refForExport,
  };
};
```

And the outcome image

[image: chart with serif font]

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am facing similar issue.

Comment: I switched to different exporting library - html-to-image, everything is fine now